# How to get the complete list of tags related to a particular term?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, data-explorer

Within the Tags page of StackOverflow ([stackoverflow.com/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)), a search for "google" gives 50 results max, but there is  234 related tags in SO.

Here is what we have:

- the popular-sorted list only gives the first 50 tags. The most popular is *google-app-engine* (21121 questions) and the least is *google-contacts* (247),
- the name-sorted list gives 50 tags too, from *google-account* to *google-caja* (so "google" tags followed by "a" and "b" only),
- the new-sorted list gives 3 tags created in the last ten days.

I would like to have the full list of tags related to *google*. How do I do that? There is no tool to navigate to the next pages, no number I can change in the url.

Thanks!

Comment: @Richard Tingle - True. It is somehow weird that the search result is truncated to the first 50 elements. BTW, is there a necessity for that? Word-based search for questions allows browsing.

Comment: Is there any reason by the way for which you want to get that list?

Comment: @Jerry I just found out about [Google big query](https://cloud.google.com/products/big-query), and wanted to know if there were some other hidden things. The tags would probably be a good way a to get both the service's name and its popularity.

Comment: @Oh, okay. Based on this, I edited the query I wrote so that there is also the count of the number of times the tags have been used; and sorted them for a better identification of popularity among the community.

Comment: Nice one - many thanks! Still puzzled by the rationale of this limit in the SO web site...

Comment: I guess that like me initially, the devs didn't know why something like that would be useful. Perhaps it just makes things a bit faster if you've got only top 50 tags to retrieve, but I can't say anything here, I don't know how SO works behind the curtains :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

```
select * from Tags where TagName like 'google%'
```

Just did it in https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/141837

Comment: Thanks - but these are the first 20 of the popular-sorted list. No obvious option to expand to `all` that I can see.

Comment: Have you tried going to http://stackoverflow.com/tags and writing "google"? Over there it does show you all of them.

Comment: This is the page where you have the 50 max list. I edited the question to add this information.

Comment: @Magla I just updated to a brand new way of getting it. Hope it helps.

Comment: That is exactly the list I wanted - I didn't know about data.stackechange. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the database of the site found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com) and run an SQL query. I'm not too SQL savvy myself, but I ran a simple script to get [234 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/141834/query-to-get-all-the-tags-containing-a-certain-text).

The only downsite I can think of is that this database is updated every week, so that the results might be outdated by a few days.