# No pagination on /tags when searching regardless of result set size

Tags: bug, tags, search, pagination

When searching via the `tagfilter` input on the /tags page the filtered results only ever returns one page of results. Pagination is never available regardless of search query.

Here is an example of searching "http-" on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name):

[image: Snip of the /tags page with "http-" entered in the input field]

Notice there is exactly one page of results with no pagination links. This despite the fact that there are [significantly more](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1617623/tag-search-by-name?TagSearch=http-) results that match this pattern than the 36 shown.

It appears the `/filter/tags-for-index` for route always returns the same empty pagination div regardless of the search results:

```html
<div class="s-pagination site1 themed pager float-right">
</div>
```

---

This appears to be true network wide. [Searching "microsoft"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAwE6.png) on [Super User /tags](https://superuser.com/tags?tab=popular) returns a single page of results despite there being [many more matches available](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1617625/tag-search-by-name?TagSearch=microsoft).

Comment: Extremely related (and possible duplicate) [How to get the complete list of tags related to a particular term?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200120/1017231)

Comment: I agree it's related, but I think the intentionality is a bit different. I know I can search SEDE (there's two in this post). I'm not looking for _how_ to get this information; I would like either the partially build pagination to be supported (like it is on the top-level page and for /users search) _or_ provide __any__ indication that the results are _very_ abridged and this search is in no way representative of all the available tags on the site.

Comment: Said slightly differently: I consider this a [bug] (and not a [feature-request]) because the /tags page does not function like the (almost identical) /users page where pagination is supported (_e.g._ [/users search "test" page 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=month&search=test))

Comment: All good, that's why I didn't vote to close initially - it's only a duplicate if you consider that solution good enough to make this bug not necessary.

Comment: This appears to be intentional, but I'm not sure why. The code has always limited tag searches to only returning one page of matches, intentionally cutting it off to prevent pagination showing up and not accepting any paging parameters. It was further limited to only 20 matches for the mobile theme, when that existed, for whatever reason.

Comment: I figured it was somewhat intentional due to the fact that the search field value is not persistent across page loads and the parameters are not stored in the URL (the way they are on the /users search). FWIW if there's some reason why this _can't_ be implemented I'd settle for _any_ indication on the results that the results are abridged (significantly so in the sample cases).